# C# How can i use parameter function in my hangman game

Tags: c#

I have been asked by my teacher to store my functions inside a parameter driven function and replacing the switch with an if statement. I have no idea how i am supposed to do this. Any help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
class Hangman
{
    public static int lives = 5;
    static string[] wordBank = { "study", "cat", "dress", "shoes", "lipstick" };
    static ArrayList wordList = new ArrayList(wordBank);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Title = "C# Hangman";
        Console.WriteLine("Hang man!");
        string response = "";
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Command (1. Add Words, 2. List Words , 3. Play , 4. Exit) Pick 1-4: ");
            response = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (response)
            {
                case "1":
                    AddWord();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    ListWords();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    Play();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    break;
            }
        } while (response != "4");

    }

    static void AddWord()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the word to add: ");
        String temp = Console.ReadLine();
        wordList.Add(temp);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} was added to the dictionary!", temp);
    }
    static void ListWords()
    {
        foreach (Object obj in wordList)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    static void AskLives()

    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter number of lives?");
            lives = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch
        {

            AskLives();
        }
    }
    static void Play()
    {
        Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);           
        string wordToGuess = wordList[random.Next(0, wordList.Count)].ToString();
        string wordToGuessUppercase = wordToGuess.ToUpper();
        StringBuilder displayToPlayer = new StringBuilder(wordToGuess.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.Length; i++)
        displayToPlayer.Append('-');
        List<char> correctGuesses = new List<char>();
        List<char> incorrectGuesses = new List<char>();
        bool won = false;
        int lettersRevealed = 0;
        string input;
        char guess;
        AskLives();
        while (!won && lives > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current word: " + displayToPlayer);
            Console.Write("Guess a letter: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            guess = input[0];

            if (correctGuesses.Contains(guess))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You've already tried '{0}', and it was correct!", guess);
                continue;
            }
            else if (incorrectGuesses.Contains(guess))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You've already tried '{0}', and it was wrong!", guess);
                continue;
            }

            if (wordToGuessUppercase.Contains(guess))
            {
                correctGuesses.Add(guess);

                for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (wordToGuessUppercase[i] == guess)
                    {
                        displayToPlayer[i] = wordToGuess[i];
                        lettersRevealed++;
                    }
                }

                if (lettersRevealed == wordToGuess.Length)
                    won = true;
            }
            else
            {
                incorrectGuesses.Add(guess);

                Console.WriteLine("Nope, there's no '{0}' in it!", guess);
                lives--;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(displayToPlayer.ToString());
        }

        if (won)
            Console.WriteLine("You won!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("You lost! It was '{0}'", wordToGuess);

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you can't get started on your assignment, ask your instructor for help. They're being paid to provide you with the education needed in order to complete it, and it would appear they have not yet done so.

Comment: This was actually the end of my assignment i did everything else. However  the person below has solved my issue. I think i was just misunderstanding how to create the "NewMethod"

Comment: While that answer may have done the work for you, I know that was what your instructor intended when you were given the assignment. I'm absolutely certain the instructor wanted to see you do that work yourself instead of depending on the IDE to do it for you. What do you do in the future when using a language that doesn't have that functionality? Nothing, because you won't know how. It's better to learn to actually do the work, instead of just taking credit for the work of others. Earn the degree you're paying to get.

Comment: Actually i understand how this works now. After looking at it i realised i needed to include the var type within the () whereas before i had just (response) and not (string response). I wasn't just taking the code to cheat. I actually learnt from it.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the switch block and select "Quick Actions."
[image]

Rename the function after applying the change.
[image]

Comment: i think this is exactly what i was looking for, i was able to work off of this thank you